Question about the Inverse Function Theorem from Güler's *Foundations of Optimization*
I'm working through the Inverse Function Theorem as presented in Foundations of Optimization by O. Güler, and I came across a detail in the proof that I'm having trouble understanding. I’d really appreciate any insights or clarifications from those more familiar with this result.
Here’s the statement of the theorem and the proof as it appears in the book. I've highlighted the part that seems tricky to me, and I’d love to hear how others interpret it.
Theorem 3.24 (Inverse Function Theorem)
Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, $x_0 \in X$, and $f$ be a $C^1$ mapping from a neighborhood of $x_0$ into $Y$. If $Df(x_0) : X \to Y$ is invertible, then $f$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism on a neighborhood of $x_0$. Moreover, if $f$ is $C^k$ on $\Omega$, then $f$ is a $C^k$ diffeomorphism on a neighborhood of $x_0$.
Proof
Define $A = Df(x_0)$. For the open mapping theorem we have that $A^{-1}$ is a continuous linear map; thus
$$
\|A^{-1}\| = \sup_{\|y\| = 1} \|A^{-1} y\| < \infty.
$$
As noted in the proof of Theorem 3.23, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that
$$
\|f(x_2) - f(x_1) - A(x_2 - x_1)\| \leq \epsilon \|x_2 - x_1\| \quad \text{for all } x_1, x_2 \in U. \tag{3.14}
$$
This implies that $f$ is one-to-one in a neighborhood of $x_0$, because if $x_1 \neq x_2$ and $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then
$$
\|A(x_1 - x_2)\| = \|f(x_1) - f(x_2) - A(x_1 - x_2)\| \leq \epsilon \|x_1 - x_2\| \leq \epsilon \|A^{-1}\| \cdot \|A(x_1 - x_2)\|,
$$
which cannot hold if $\epsilon > 0$ is small enough.
Moreover, the inclusion (3.11) in Grave's Theorem implies that there exist open neighborhoods $U \ni x_0$ and $V \ni y_0$ such that $f : U \to V$ is one-to-one and onto, and the inequality (3.12) implies that $f^{-1} : V \to U$ is continuous. Setting $y_i := f(x_i)$, $i = 1, 2$, we have
$$
\|f^{-1}(y_2) - f^{-1}(y_1) - A^{-1}(y_2 - y_1)\| = \|x_2 - x_1 - A^{-1}(f(x_2) - f(x_1))\|
$$
$$
\leq \|A^{-1}\| \cdot \|f(x_2) - f(x_1) - A(x_2 - x_1)\| \leq \epsilon \|A^{-1}\| \cdot \|x_2 - x_1\|
$$
$$
\leq \epsilon \|A^{-1}\| \|y_2 - y_1\|,
$$
for all $y_1, y_2 \in V$, where the second inequality follows from (3.14), and the last inequality from (3.12). This proves that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $y_0$ with $Df^{-1}(y_0) = A^{-1} = Df(x_0)^{-1}$.
If the neighborhood $U$ containing $x_0$ is chosen small enough such that $Df(x)$ is invertible for every $x \in U$, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism between $U$ and $V = f(U)$.  It follows that if $y = f(x)$, then
$$
Df^{-1}(y) = Df(x)^{-1},
$$
that is,
$$
D(f^{-1}) = \text{Inv} \circ Df \circ f^{-1}, \tag{3.15}
$$
on $f(U)$, where $\text{Inv}$ is the map sending a nonsingular matrix to its inverse. Since $\text{Inv}$ is infinitely differentiable (see Example 1.28) and $Df$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous, it follows that $f^{-1} \in C^1$. If, moreover, $f \in C^2$, that is, $Df \in C^1$, it follows from (3.15) that $D(f^{-1}) \in C^1$, that is, $f^{-1} \in C^2$. Induction on $k$ settles the general case.

The part I find difficult to understand this:
If the neighborhood $U$ containing $x_0$ is chosen small enough such that $Df(x)$ is invertible for every $x \in U$, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism between $U$ and $V = f(U)$.
The part I find difficult to understand is this:
"If the neighborhood $U$ containing $x_0$ is chosen small enough such that $Df(x)$ is invertible for every $x \in U$, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism between $U$ and $V = f(U)$."
How can this neighborhood exist? Isn't it kind of what we are trying to prove? All the proofs that I came up with rely on finite dimension: determinant or compactness.
This was just a curiosity, and I'd like to have a fourth proof of this theorem—it’s nice to collect them!
Thanks in advance for your help!
